# how to stop auditing create operations in hibernate envers?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-envers

I just want to audit the update and delete operations but hibernate envers also logs the INSERT operations, how can we stop auditing the insert operations?

**application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.envers.default_catalog=demo_audit
spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.listeners.envers.autoRegister=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.envers.autoRegisterListeners=false
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to interrupt envers via events => look [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html#d5e4275) for detail description of conditional auditing.
Those steps work for spring-boot:

1. Override onPostInsert method

```
package com.example.stackoverflow1.audit;

import com.example.stackoverflow1.model.Soup;
import org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversService;
import org.hibernate.envers.event.spi.EnversPostInsertEventListenerImpl;
import org.hibernate.event.spi.PostInsertEvent;

public class CustomAuditEventListenerPostInsert extends EnversPostInsertEventListenerImpl {


    public CustomAuditEventListenerPostInsert(EnversService enversService) {
        super(enversService);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostInsert(PostInsertEvent event) {
        // super.onPostInsert(event); if this is called, the audit is executed.
        // without it there is no audit entry
    }

}
```

2. You need to register your custom onPostInsertListener to envers:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversService;
import org.hibernate.event.service.spi.EventListenerRegistry;
import org.hibernate.event.spi.EventType;
import org.hibernate.jpa.HibernateEntityManagerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AuditConfig {

    private HibernateEntityManagerFactory hibernateEntityManagerFactory;

    @PostConstruct
    public void registerEnversListeners() {
        EnversService enversService =
                hibernateEntityManagerFactory
                        .getSessionFactory()
                        .getServiceRegistry()
                        .getService(EnversService.class);

        EventListenerRegistry listenerRegistry = hibernateEntityManagerFactory.getSessionFactory().getServiceRegistry().getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
        listenerRegistry.setListeners(EventType.POST_INSERT, new CustomAuditEventListenerPostInsert(enversService));
    }
}
```

Edit1: This only works if the parent entity has no audited child entities. Otherwise an updated statement is added instead after the creation.
Therefore I need also an answer on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59633260/hibernate-envers-prevent-version-on-onpostdelete)

Edit2: Check out this manual trigger for audit entries - https://developer.jboss.org/thread/274280

Answer (score 1):

Auditing can be disabled for each Hibernate `EventType` by digging into the `EntityManagerFactory`.

```
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor;
import org.hibernate.event.service.spi.EventListenerRegistry;
import org.hibernate.event.spi.EventType;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.envers.repository.config.EnableEnversRepositories;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

@Configuration
@EnableEnversRepositories
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class EnversConfig {
    private final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @PostConstruct
    private void disableAuditingInsertEvents() {
        entityManagerFactory
                .unwrap(SessionFactoryImplementor.class)
                .getServiceRegistry()
                .getService(EventListenerRegistry.class)
                .getEventListenerGroup(EventType.POST_INSERT)
                .clearListeners();
    }
}
```

Note this approach assumes there are no additional `POST_INSERT` event listeners, since this clears them all.