# Hibernate Envers: prevent version on onPostDelete

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, hibernate-envers

I would like to stop Hibernate Envers from creating a version if the audited entity is deleted. 
The issue is, that instead of an delete version (REVTYPE: 2) and updated version (REVTYPE: 1) is inserted without calling onPostUpdate Event of Envers.

**pom.xml:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>stackoverflow1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>stackoverflow1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**auditConfig.java:**
    package com.example.stackoverflow1.audit;

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversService;
import org.hibernate.event.service.spi.EventListenerRegistry;
import org.hibernate.event.spi.EventType;
import org.hibernate.jpa.HibernateEntityManagerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AuditConfig {

private HibernateEntityManagerFactory hibernateEntityManagerFactory;

@PostConstruct
public void registerEnversListeners() {
    EnversService enversService =
            hibernateEntityManagerFactory
                    .getSessionFactory()
                    .getServiceRegistry()
                    .getService(EnversService.class);

    EventListenerRegistry listenerRegistry = hibernateEntityManagerFactory.getSessionFactory().getServiceRegistry().getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
    listenerRegistry.setListeners(EventType.POST_INSERT, new CustomAuditEventListenerPostInsert(enversService));
    listenerRegistry.setListeners(EventType.POST_DELETE, new CustomAuditEventListenerPostDelete(enversService));
}
}
```

**customEventListenerPostDelete.java:**

```
package com.example.stackoverflow1.audit;

import com.example.stackoverflow1.model.Soup;
import org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversService;
import org.hibernate.envers.event.spi.EnversPostDeleteEventListenerImpl;
import org.hibernate.event.spi.PostDeleteEvent;

public class CustomAuditEventListenerPostDelete extends EnversPostDeleteEventListenerImpl {


    public CustomAuditEventListenerPostDelete(EnversService enversService) {
        super(enversService);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostDelete(PostDeleteEvent event) {
        if (event.getEntity() instanceof Soup){
            Soup soup = ((Soup) event.getEntity());
            System.out.println("DELETE: " + soup);
        }
    }

}
```

**Controller.java:**

```
import com.sun.tools.javac.util.List;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SoupController {

    private SoupRepository soupRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "create")
    public Soup create() {
        Ingredient ingredient = Ingredient.builder().name("ingredient").build();
        Soup soup = Soup.builder()
                .name("Soup")
                .ingredients(List.of(ingredient))
                .build();
        return soupRepository.save(soup);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "delete")
    public void delete() {
        soupRepository.deleteById(1L);
    }

}
```

After /create followed by /delete I would like to have **just one Entry** in Soup_AUD.

ID      REV     REVTYPE     NAME

1       1       0           Soup

But instead I've got:

ID      REV     REVTYPE     NAME

1       1       0           Soup

1       2       1           Soup

**How can I avoid this delete audit?**

> Project can be checked out -> https://github.com/MoritzMeinhardt/hibernate-envers.git

Comment: It seem to be, that hibernate is getting the soup, deleting the ingredients, updating the soup and then delete the soup. 
Without any ingredients is works as expected for me.

Comment: I am maybe using this manual trigger solution https://developer.jboss.org/thread/274280

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're facing this issue because of how Envers handles applying changes to the owning entity of a collection.

You could try setting `org.hibernate.envers.revision_on_collection_change` to `false`, but be mindful this is for all audited entities and currently can't be targetted to a specific entity type or relation.

I've logged [HHH-13819](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13819) to follow-up on this.